# Condition execute for different columns in each row

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

```
A = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0];

B = [2,5;
     1,6;
     3,10];
```

Expected Output Cell Array:

```
C = [1,1,1,1;            %// 2-3-4, 3-4-5, 4-5, 5
     0,0,1,1,1,0;        %// 1-2-3, 2-3-4, 3-4-5, 4-5-6, 5-6, 6
     1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0];   %// 3-4-5, 4-5-6, 5-6-7, 7-8-9, 8-9-10, 9-10, 10
```

Matrix B includes which columns should be used to execute the condition on Matrix A. For example, first row of B is 2 and 5; so elements between 2nd 5th column of matrix A should be used to execute the condition. Second row of B is 1 and 6; so elements between 1st 6th column should be used to execute the condition. And so on...

The condition: if sum of successive 3 elements is bigger than or equal to 1 then write 1 to matrix C; otherwise write 0. For example, A includes 0,1,0 as three successive elements (sum is 0+1+0=1), so write 1 to matrix C. Another example, first three elements of A in second row are 0,0,0 (sum is 0), so write 0 to matrix C. And so on...

> **"Sometimes it can be considered only 1 or 2 successive elements."**

For example, condition execution of first row of A ends with 5th column, so only value 5th column should be considered; which is 1. So 1 is written to matrix C.

**Explaining the first row of C:**

> 1, since (sum of 2,3,4 elements of A(1,:)) >= 1
>
> 1, since (sum of 3,4,5 elements of A(1,:)) >= 1
>
> since max limit is 5, only 2 successive elements are taken here
>       1, since (sum of 4,5 elements alone of A(1,:)) >= 1
>
> since max limit is 5, only 1 successive element is taken here
>       1, since (sum of 5th element alone of A(1,:)) >= 1

Without for loop, only with matrix operations, how can I do this complex task? or any trick?

Comment: " (sum is 0+1+0=1), so write 1 to matrix C", why? You said, the sum should be *bigger* than 1. I guess you mean *greater than or equal to 1* instead of "bigger than 1"

Comment: How did you get the matrix `C`? Also, how do you define successive elements, row-wise, column-wise? For example, In the first row, columns 2 to 5, you get [1;1] in matrix C. How do you get the next two 1s?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar yes it should be greater than equal to 1.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar row-wise. The third 1 is result of two successive elements of first row (0,1) and The fourth 1 is result of one successive element of first row (1). Consider that I can execute the condition only until 5th element of first row which is written matrix B.

Comment: Thanks @Santhan for editing, now question is much more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`mat2cell`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), [`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), [`im2col`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) and [`any`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html)

```
subMatLen = 3;

%// Converting both A & B matrix to Cell Arrays to perform operations Row-wise
AC = mat2cell(A,ones(1,size(A,1)),size(A,2));
BC = mat2cell(B,ones(1,size(B,1)),size(B,2));

%// Getting only the columns of each rows within the limits specified  by Matrix B
%// Also appended with zeros for my own convenience as it wont affect the 'summing' process
out = cellfun(@(x,y) [x(y(1):y(2)),zeros(1,subMatLen-1)],AC, BC, 'uni', 0);

%// Finally taking each 1x3 sliding sub-matrix and returning 1 if `any` of it is non-zero
%// which is equivalent to summing and checking whether they are >= 1
out = cellfun(@(x) any(im2col(x, [1,subMatLen], 'sliding')), out, 'uni', 0);
```

**Your Sample Input:**

```
A = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0;
     0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0];

B = [2,5;
     1,6;
     3,10];
```

**Output:**

```
>> celldisp(out)

out{1} =

 1     1     1     1


out{2} =

 0     0     1     1     1     0


out{3} =

 1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

If you want them as a single row or column matrix, you could add this to the bottom of the code:

```
out = cat(2,out{:})
```

*or*

```
out = (cat(2,out{:})).'
```

Comment: When I wrote this question, I did not expect someone will answer it. Thanks @Santhan. It works. How can I make successive element number as variable (in the question it is 3). In my code when I change 3 with 6, at last line of your code, result matrix was not correct.

Comment: @oarar, I'm glad it helped. Edited my code.. you don't have to edit the code. just change the `subMatLen` at the top. It should work :)